# Wifi Not Working after Suspend/Screen Off Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit Daily Build and got this problem. There wasn't any problem in 13.10. I have a Dell Latitude D630 with Intel Wifi, Driver : iwl4965.
I have tried the solution mentioned at http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/fix-wireless-or-wired-network-not.html but its not working. Here is the output of sudo lshw -C network:

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 61
       serial: 00:1f:3b:d3:ce:01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl4965 driverversion=3.13.0-18-generic firmware=228.61.2.24 ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:44 memory:fe8fe000-fe8fffff
```

Comment: Is this still an issue with a fresh install?